# Rails abstract class has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class, polymorphic-associations

As the title suggests, this isn't going to make any sense. Imagine the scenario:

I have the following models: `Game`, `GameType`, and `Champion`. I would like only games of a certain `GameType` (like MOBA) to have a `has_many` relationship to the `Champion` model; where others (like FPS, etc.) would not.

My first inclination was to make a `GameTypeMoba` abstract class, where all classes that inherit from it could have some of its properties (such as having champions). However, I know this doesn't make sense since a class that is not tied to a table can't have table relationships. Further, it just seems like a shitty, WET (opposite of DRY) approach if I could somehow hack it together.

I hope someone has a simple solution that *doesn't* involve messy app logic. Although I'd also accept "retard, go to bed" at this point as well.

Comment: Why can't you just ignore the `has_many` when `GameType` is `MOBA`?

Comment: Yeah that's a solution, I was hoping for someone to point to a flaw in my architecture/design.

Comment: OK, let me put it this way then: the flaw in your architecture/design is that you are trying to architecture something that doesn't need architecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mischa is right, in this case it doesn't seem like there's anything better/cleaner that can be done. And having an unneeded relation for a subset of records isn't really a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Checking out the Rails Guides "has_many" association reference (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference), you may be able to use the condition option on the association declaration. The example provided in the documentation:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :confirmed_orders, :class_name => "Order",
    :conditions => "confirmed = 1"
end
```

In your situation, I assume you would want to use the :class_name of "GameType" with :conditions => "MOBA = ".

Comment: I think you're onto something, but I think the `:class_name` param is expecting the class that will contain the field(s) in the `:conditions` param.

Comment: Agreed, so: class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :confirmed_orders, :class_name => "Order",
    :conditions => "confirmed = 1"
end

Comment: Yeah. So doing something like `has_many :champions, :class_name => "GameType", :conditions => "name = MOBA"` would line up the `:conditions` with the `:class_name`, but would not incorporate the `Champion` model I don't think.

Comment: Ahh, yes - I think you're right. Interesting question though - will keep thinking on it.

Comment: You're both right about the condition being on the child. I don't understand why you'd work so hard to prevent the actual relationship though. What I've done in the past instead is: a) disable the function to add children (Champs for you) from the parent views. Then for the Child model, add a validation which checks the parent type. E.g: GAMES_WITH_CHAMPS.include?(self.game.type)